# Cumulative count for empty groups in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

Say that you have a table named XYZ in power bi.
this table contains three columns: 'category' (of type text), 'item (of type text), and 'status' as a sequential number from 1 to 28 ( where 1 is the first status of an item and 28 is the last status of an item).
NOT every 'category' has 'item's on every 'status' ... this is an important note.

I want to create a new measure on this XYZ table, that will count cumulatively the number of items under each status per category, where the smaller status counts the number of items under it and all the number of items that have status higher than it.... i.e. the count for status (1) = the count of all the items ... the count for status (26) = the count of items that has status (26) + the count of items that has status (27) + the count of items that has status (28).
Another thing to clarify is that for those category/status that has no items belongs to them, consider the value as 0 then do the calculation as above... this is an important note and this is my challenge

Comment: Update your question with a sample table and desired results in [markdown format](https://tabletomarkdown.com/). Also include any Dax expressions you have tried.